# W1024 Combining signed and unsigned types - widened both operands

Tags: delphi

How can I prevent this warning?
[DCC Warning] uFvSystem.pas(293): W1024 Combining signed and unsigned types - widened both operands

```
function LinkerTimestamp: TDateTime; overload;
begin
  Result := PImageNtHeaders(HInstance + PImageDosHeader(HInstance)^._lfanew)
   ^.FileHeader.TimeDateStamp / SecsPerDay + UnixDateDelta;
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message indicates that you are performing integer arithmetic with mixed signed and unsigned operands. The only integer arithmetic is here:

```
HInstance + PImageDosHeader(HInstance)^._lfanew
```

The first operand is unsigned, the second is signed, even though it must be positive.

You can suppress the warning with a cast. It is better to perform the arithmetic in an unsigned context and so avoid range check errors. Hence the cast is placed around the second operand:

```
HInstance + NativeUInt(PImageDosHeader(HInstance)^._lfanew)
```

or

```
HInstance + Cardinal(PImageDosHeader(HInstance)^._lfanew)
```

if you have an older Delphi that does not have `NativeUInt`.

However, you are actually performing arithmetic on pointers and so I would write it like this:

```
PByte(HInstance) + PImageDosHeader(HInstance)^._lfanew
```

or

```
PAnsiChar(HInstance) + PImageDosHeader(HInstance)^._lfanew
```

in older Delphi versions for which `PByte` does not support arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

The `_lfanew` field is a `LongInt`. The `HInstance` variable is probably a `THandle`, which is an alias for `Cardinal` or some equivalent type. There are your signed and unsigned types.

What type should the sum have? The range of possible values is one bit wider than the size of `THandle`. (The sum of an *m*-bit number and an *n*-bit number needs at most `max(m, n)` bits.) Neither of the types involved is big enough, so the compiler promotes them both to a wider type that will accommodate the full range.

You know something about the ranges of these variables that the compiler doesn't. In particular, you know that `_lfanew` is an offset into a range of memory that has `HInstance` as its base. As long as there's no file corruption, the sum of `HInstance` and `_lfanew` will be a valid address, so you can safely type-cast `_lfanew` to an unsigned type with the confidence that the sum won't overflow:

```
Result := PImageNtHeaders(HInstance + UIntPtr(PImageDosHeader(HInstance)^._lfanew))
  ^.FileHeader.TimeDateStamp / SecsPerDay + UnixDateDelta;
```

Use `UIntPtr` if your version of Delphi offers it. Otherwise, `NativeUInt` or `Cardinal` will do.

Comment: The second paragraph doesn't really justify the warning. Even if the two types are the same, an addition can overflow. I think that the warning is really because the compiler has no grounds to pick a type for the expression. The expression is a + b. Should a + b have the type of a, or the type of b?